# HTML Page with GridLayout and Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, responsive-design

I have the following problem:

**CSS-FILE:**

I have a website which I split in two parts. Top Part (the .grid.full) uses 86 % of the screen, the Bottom Part (grid.bott) uses 14% screen. (grid.full and grid.bott are in the css-file)

**HTML File**

I want to insert a Button in the bottom part (in CSS: grid.bott). So the grid.bott is defined in the css file as 14% height.  My Button is inserted in a table and defined in the CSS (.buttbott). How can I adjust the height of the button compliant with the bottom part. I want the button height 80 percent of the size from the bottom part. The Bottom part has a height of 14% from the screen.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}


/* grid */

.grid {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Use 43% of the screen */

.grid .span {
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  height: 43%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* 3 columns */
}


/* Use 86% of the screen */

.grid .full {
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  height: 86%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* 3 columns */
}


/* Use 14% of the screen*/

.grid .bott {
  background: #fdc400;
  float: left;
  height: 14%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* 3 columns */
}


/* Buttons für BOTTOM */

.buttbott {
  border: 1px outset blue;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 110%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="full">
      <br/>
      <h3>TEST PAGE</h3>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="bott">
      <div class="container">
        <table id="buttons">
          <tr>
            <th>
              <input id="index" class="buttbott" type="button" value="HOME" />
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the button have a height of 80% of the height of the `.bott` element, we'll first need to define the height of the other elements in the `.bott` element. Namely:

```
.container,
#buttons,
#buttons tr {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Then we can set the height of the button to `80%`.

```
/* Buttons für BOTTOM */

.buttbott {
  height: 80%;
}
```

Here's the full demo:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}


/* grid */

.grid {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Use 43% of the screen */

.grid .span {
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  height: 43%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* 3 columns */
}


/* Use 86% of the screen */

.grid .full {
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  height: 86%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* 3 columns */
}


/* Use 14% of the screen*/

.grid .bott {
  background: #fdc400;
  float: left;
  height: 14%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* 3 columns */
}

.container,
#buttons,
#buttons tr {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Buttons für BOTTOM */

.buttbott {
  border: 1px outset blue;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 80%;
  width: 110px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 110%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="full">
      <br/>
      <h3>TEST PAGE</h3>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="bott">
      <div class="container">
        <table id="buttons">
          <tr>
            <th>
              <input id="index" class="buttbott" type="button" value="HOME" />
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think this solution don`t work. when i display the example in the full page mode the button don´t have 80% height of the .bott element.

Comment: Odd. Appears to be 80% when I view in full page. Here's what I see - https://imgur.com/a/ZLcuP

Comment: i think the problem is, i use the firefox 57. with the ie 11 it works. how can i adjust it to work with both?
Can you explain the solution? i am new with css girds

Comment: There's no use of the CSS `grid` here, at least in the code within the question. Was that left out of the CSS in the original question?

Comment: ok. no i don`t have left out anything. but why is there a difference between internet explorer and firefox? In firefox it dosen`t work

Comment: i've updated the solution. we need to define the height of the table and table row.

Comment: One thing, how can i get the same width for all buttons? (i want to insert more then one buttons). Lets Say i want 110% of the height of the bott element? And when i insert the Buttons in  "full" part i need the same height, width as the buttons in the bottom part

Comment: Give a specific `width` to all buttons, like `button {width: 150px;}`

Comment: that`s suitable  when i want a responsive design? 
And when i insert the Buttons in "full" part i need the same height as the buttons in the bottom part. how can i achieve this?